# Can't load .pkl file

Tags: python, k-means

I am using minibatch k-means clustering. The .pkl file is generated using Ubuntu then we would like to load it to Raspberry Pi which has an OS of Raspbian. After doing so, I've encountered the error below.

The libraries used are the following:

- scikit-learn v0.18
- scipy v0.18
- python 2.7
- numpy 1.11.2

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!
[image]

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch; next field is at offset 12 but 16 expected
```

Comment: am not sure, but try loading that .pkl on another computer. make sure it works on another computer too.

Comment: we already tried loading it on another computer but the error is still the same.

Comment: so you tried in different computer it doesn't work, but in same computer it does? So the only solution is make your pkl in the machine, where you want to run it